# Tree with boost shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have created this simple program to learn shared_ptr

```
using namespace std;
 #define Yes 1
 #define No 0

class Node
{
public:
boost::shared_ptr<Node> left;
boost::shared_ptr<Node> rigth;
int nVal;
Node();
Node(int);
~Node();
int getVal(void);
void setVal(int);

 };
```

Methods

```
Node::Node()
{
cout << "creating node empty" << endl;
nVal = 0;
left.reset();
rigth.reset();

}

Node::~Node() 
{
cout << "entering destructor"  << nVal << endl;
}

Node::Node(int n)
{
cout << "creating node with value" << n << endl;
nVal = n;
left.reset();
rigth.reset();
}

int Node::getVal(void)
{
cout << "returning value" << endl;
return this->nVal;
}

void Node::setVal(int n)
{
cout << "setting value" << endl;
nVal = n;
}
```

Tree

```
  class Tree 
   {
  public:
 boost::shared_ptr<Node> root;
  Tree();
  ~Tree();
  void findParent(int n, int &found, boost::shared_ptr<Node> &parent);
  void add(int n);
  void post(boost::weak_ptr<Node> q);
  void del(int n);

  };

Tree::Tree()
{
root.reset();
}

 Tree::~Tree()
{
cout << "deleting tree" << endl;
}
```

Tree find parent

```
void Tree::findParent(int n, int& found, boost::shared_ptr<Node> &parent)
{
   boost::shared_ptr<Node> q;
  found = No;

 cout << "looking parent of" << n << endl;
 if(parent.use_count() == 0)
 {
  cout << "not found" << endl;
  return;
  }

q=parent;

 while (!q.use_count())
{
  if( q->nVal == n)
  {
      cout << "found" << endl;
      found = Yes;
      return;

  }

  if (q->rigth->nVal)
  {
      cout << "looking to the rigth" << endl;
      parent = q;
      q = q->left;
  }
  else
  {
      cout << "looking to the left" << endl;
      parent = q;
      q = q->rigth;
  }
 }
}
```

Tree add

```
void Tree::add(int n)
 {
 int found;

boost::shared_ptr<Node> parent;
findParent(n, found,parent);
if(found == Yes)
{
    cout << "no such node exist" << endl;
}

else
{

    boost::shared_ptr<Node> t(new Node(n));  
    t->rigth.reset();
    t->left.reset();

    if (parent.get()== 0)
    {
        parent = t;
    }
    else
    {
        parent->nVal > n ? parent->left = t : parent->rigth = t;
    }
}
}
```

Main:

```
int THREADS_HOW_MANY = 0;

int main()
{
Tree bt;
bt.add(10);
bt.add(4);
bt.add(12);
bt.add(2);
bt.add(8);
bt.add(15);
bt.add(15);



return 0;
}
```

Now the q is, why is is not working, why is giving this output:

```
  empty constructor only the root is reset
  looking parent of10
  not found
  creating node with value10
  entering destructor10
  looking parent of4
  not found
  creating node with value4
  entering destructor4
  looking parent of12
  not found
  creating node with value12
  entering destructor12
 looking parent of2
 not found
  creating node with value2
 entering destructor2
```

Fixed it now is diff it seem that the nodes are just being created and deleted not added to a tree why??

Comment: parent.reset(); 
 if(parent.use_count() == 0) // this is always true!

Comment: changed it (:, thanks. Still not going correctly

Comment: q=parent; 
 while (!q.use_count()) // always false, loop won't run
In short, can't you just step your own code in the debugger and see what goes there?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code:

```
// from Tree::add
boost::shared_ptr t(new Node(n));
boost::shared_ptr parent(new Node(n));
findParent(n, found,parent);

// from tree::findParent
boost::shared_ptr q(new Node(n));
```

So, the program creates node for every value 3 times, as requested. shared_ptr ensures, that every node is properly destructed, so Node destructor is called 3 times as well.

Comment: ok how do I fix it (:, how do i tell it to only point to the created node and no do is again.

Comment: nv i got it by deleting the new node(n) parts i still don't get why is it not pointing to the sons.